# How to get the marker location (leaflet serach Nominatim)

Tags: javascript, properties, leaflet

I am not sure, how to get the lat and lng from the marker location that is displayed on the map?

Here a jsfiddle (Sorry, don't know how to insert js from github):
https://jsfiddle.net/qkcc3r2o/2/

The Input field is not shown in the jsfiddle  :(

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var map = new L.Map('map-adress', {zoom: 3, center: new L.latLng([24.61, -34.63]) });
map.addLayer(new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}));


var markersLayer = new L.LayerGroup();  //layer contain searched elements
map.addLayer(markersLayer);

map.addControl( new L.Control.Search({
    container: 'findbox-adress',
    url: 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&street={s}',
    jsonpParam: 'json_callback',
    propertyName: 'display_name',
    propertyLoc: ['lat','lon'],
    marker: L.circleMarker([0,0],{radius:30}),
    autoCollapse: false,
    collapsed: false,
    autoType: false,
    minLength: 2,
    autoResize: false,
    zoom: 18
}) );

$(".search-button").remove();
$( ".search-input" ).attr( "Placeholder", "Street, No." );

console.log(map.addControl.propertyLoc);
 });
```

I need the Lat Lng from the location, to add markers in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.search-input {
    font-family:Courier
}
.search-input,
.leaflet-control-search {
    max-width:400px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-search@3.0.0/dist/leaflet-search.src.css" />

<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-search@3.0.0/dist/leaflet-search.src.js"></script>
<script>

    var map = new L.Map('map', {zoom: 9, center: new L.latLng([18.5,73.8]) });
    map.addLayer(new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')); //base layer
    
    map.addControl( new L.Control.Search({
        url: 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q={s}',
        jsonpParam: 'json_callback',
        propertyName: 'display_name',
        propertyLoc: ['lat','lon'],
        marker: L.marker([0,0]).addTo(map).on('click', getLatLon),
        autoCollapse: true,
        autoType: false,
        minLength: 2
    })    
  );
  
  function getLatLon(e) {
    alert(this.getLatLng());
}
</script>
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, i'll check it tomorrow. Hope it will work. 

Comment: Welcome @c00L :)

Comment: Sweet, it's working. Thank you, it will help me a lot. :)

Comment: @c00L Great  ..  :)